# Make the title section font size in "ask question" larger in meta

Tags: discussion, font

I think the title section in meta, where we add title should have a larger font and font size. Maybe both title and body should have larger font and font size.It becomes difficult to read the text while asking questions on meta due to small font and font size.

**EDIT:-** I am referring to both font size and font.There improper combination makes the text difficult to read.Zooming is not an good solution as then one has to scroll vertically.I use `Ubuntu 12.10` with its default `mozilla firefox`.

Changing font works but it is website relative.(i.e. I may have to change settings for various websites).So I think my request is still considerable.Maybe just increasing font by 2 should do.

Comment: Screenshots do wonders with visual issues. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Ubuntu?

The form fields have several monospace font options on a first-available system (`Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif`).

I'm using Consolas but Monaco and Liberation Mono are good too.

Courier's actual font face is smaller than the other fonts at the same given size so if that's the first available font you have, that might explain the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: What package provides consolas?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using your web browser's zoom feature to make the text larger. In most browsers (like in Firefox, for example) you can use these keyboard shortcuts:

- `Ctrl`+`+` (zoom in)
- `Ctrl`+`-` (zoom out)
- `Ctrl`+`0` (return to default zoom level)

Ubuntu's terminal also has this ability, but in a terminal you also need to hold `Shift`.